# How do I connect UITextView to @IBAction using Interface Builder in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

Why am I not able to connect a UITextField in a view controller scene on Storyboard to a @IBAction? When I Ctrl drag and drop to the view controller class in the swift file, there isn't even an option to allow me to select @IBAction. Only "Outlet" and "Outlet Collection" shows. When I write the code first and then Ctrl drag, I still can't connect the text view to the @IBAction. I tried even changing the type to the parameter sender from UITextView to AnyObject, and it didn't work. Changing the type to Any doesn't solve the problem either. I wonder whether UITextView is not allowed to use @IBAction. Maybe it doesn't conform to a protocol required for connecting objects using Interface Builder.

Comment: Could you share gif or small video, that captures your screen and how you are doing it. that will help to help you further.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't create @IBAction against UITextView because UITextview doesn't inherit from UIControl class. if you see the UITextField and UITextView hierarchy you can find that both classes' view hierarchy is changed.

Comment: What *action* are you trying to connect?